# Could I create a competitive sci-fi question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question which could have a lot of statements/quotes in a single answer. But I want to add some fun like making the question a competitive one. By competitive I mean that I would create the question with rules like :

1. The Answer with most quotes/statements gets their answer as accepted.
2. The 2nd and 3rd best answer will also get mention at the last edit of question.
3. No duplication allowed, if a quote/statement is already used by someone, do not use that in your answer.

Comment: I think the usual culture of voting and accepting already values more quotes/statements quite highly on this site, when those quotes/statements are relevant. And it's already seen as unsporting to copy a quote that someone else used (when the answers are too far apart for it to be plausible that both answerers found it independently). Trying to quantify how many quotes someone has seems like it'll encourage lame answers which, in the extreme case, try to fit thousands of "quotes" into the 30,000 character limit.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that some users have complained the site is too competitive in its default state: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7360/is-scifi-stackexchange-com-a-competition

Comment: Up voted the question because it's good that you're asking _first_, but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: What question did you have in mind? Perhaps add some examples?

Comment: I personally don't find list questions to be useful or interesting. This doesn't seem like a good fit with the site; however, if you want to consider your question as just a fun challenge, I think it would be entirely appropriate for chat. (I couldn't say how many answers you'd get, but at least chat would be a place to put the question). :)

Answer (score 16):

No, I don't think this is a good idea. This is not *[Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)* or *[Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)*.

---

Some users think the site can be too competitive even as it is, see

[Is scifi.stackexchange.com a competition?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7360/19561)

---

We *do* sometimes have questions asking to identify all these *Xs*, where *X* can be robot or spaceship, usually in another work that quotes well-known *Xs* from present or past. These can turn into impromptu community challenges [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), leading to a CW-answer (but not always).

Examples include

- [Identify these "Retro Machines"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117496/19561)
- [Can you identify these Doctors of the science fiction genre in miniature formats?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/116715/19561)